# Ajax and jQuery Not working on server

Tags: jquery, ajax

Inserting data using works on xampp server but it is not working on server. I have tried many things please help me

this is the javascript code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        //Handler for .ready() called.
        $("#li_daily_operations").addClass("active");
        $("#li_add_daily_log").addClass("active");
         $('#save_btn').click(function() {
    autoSavedata()  ;
});

function autoSavedata()  
  {         

       var daily_log = CKEDITOR.instances['daily_log'].getData();// $('textarea.daily_log').val();
       var location = $('#location').val(); 
       var user_id = $('#user_id').val();  
        var post_id = $('#post_id').val();  
       if(daily_log!= '')  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"../php/add/add_daily_log.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:{ daily_log:daily_log, location:location, user_id:user_id, post_id:post_id},                      
                 success:function(data)  
                 {          
                      if(data!='')  
                      { 
                            $('#post_id').val(data);  
                      }  
                      $('#autoSave').text("Data Saved");  
                      setInterval(function(){  
                           $('#autoSave').text('');  
                      }, 3000);  
                 }  
            });  
       }            
  }  
  setInterval(function(){   
       autoSavedata();   
       }, 2000);  
    });
</script>
```

This is the php code to save data, these code works when run locally but when i put this o server it doesnt work

```
<?php  
    //Include Database Connection
 include '../../dbconnect/dbconnect.php'; 
 if(isset($_POST["daily_log"]))
 {
  $daily_log =  $_POST["daily_log"];
  $location = $_POST["location"];
  $user_id = $_POST["user_id"]; 
  if($_POST["post_id"] != '')  
  {  
    //update post  
    $sql = "UPDATE daily_log SET daily_log = '".$daily_log."' WHERE daily_log_id = '".$_POST["post_id"]."'";  
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
    echo $_POST["post_id"];         
  }  
  else  
  {  
    //insert post  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO daily_log(daily_log, data_entered_by, location, post_status) VALUES ('".$daily_log."', '".$user_id."', '".$location."', 'draft')";  
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
    echo mysqli_insert_id($conn);  
  }
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: No code, no explanation of what you've tried, no in-depth explanation of the problem.. we are more helpless than you right now

Comment: I Have added the code now

Comment: What error are you getting? You need to share more insights so that we understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

download jQuery to your root/js folder 
ex: /js/jquery.min.js then change the code:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/avesi/jquery.paulund_modal_box.js"></script>
```